# filter rows based on threshold

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Assume the following dataframe

| Ref | t1 | t2 | t3 | t4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | -3 | 2 | 7 |
| B | -2 | -4 | -1 | 3 |
| C | 1 | 6 | 3 | 9 |

I would like to add another column returning the value of columns t1, t2 or t3 if the value in these columns is above a threshold (for instance 5) otherwise use t4

So with 5 as threshold, I would be looking for :

| Ref | t1 | t2 | t3 | t4 | Criteria |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | -3 | 2 | 7 | 5 |
| B | -2 | -4 | -1 | 3 | 3 |
| C | 1 | 6 | 3 | 9 | 6 |

I could use:
group = ["t1", "t2", "t3"] and
df2 = df[(df[group] >= 5).any(axis=1)]
but that won't use "t4" if none of the columns in group is higher than 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with set first value by threshold by [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) with back filling missing values and selecting first column:

```
group = ["t1", "t2", "t3"]

m = df[group] >= 5
df['out'] = np.where(m.any(axis=1), df[group].where(m).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0], df['t4'])
print (df)
  Ref  t1  t2  t3  t4  out
0   A   5  -3   2   7  5.0
1   B  -2  -4  -1   3  3.0
2   C   1   6   3   9  6.0
```

Alternative with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
group = ["t1", "t2", "t3"]

m = df[group] >= 5

df['out'] = df[group].where(m).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0].fillna(df['t4'])
print (df)
  Ref  t1  t2  t3  t4  out
0   A   5  -3   2   7  5.0
1   B  -2  -4  -1   3  3.0
2   C   1   6   3   9  6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always try some funky arithmetic:

```
t5 = df[['t1', 't2', 't3']].max(axis=1)
t5 = t5 * (t5 >= 5) + df['t4'] * (t5 < 5)

df.insert(5, 'Criteria', t5)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Ref  t1  t2  t3  t4  Criteria
0   A   5  -3   2   7         5
1   B  -2  -4  -1   3         3
2   C   1   6   3   9         6
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
# select columns of interest
tmp = df.filter(like='t')

# use a mask to keep only the values that match the criterion
# for t4 let's pretend the values are Inf for the mask
df['Criteria'] = (tmp.where(tmp.assign(t4=np.inf).ge(5))
                     .stack().groupby(level=0).first()
                 )
```

Variant:

```
tmp = df[['t1', 't2', 't3']]
df['Criteria'] = (tmp.where(tmp.ge(5)).stack()
                     .groupby(level=0).first()
                     .combine_first(df['t4'])
                 )
```

Output:

```
  Ref  t1  t2  t3  t4  Criteria
0   A   5  -3   2   7       5.0
1   B  -2  -4  -1   3       3.0
2   C   1   6   3   9       6.0
```